# SQL output: Is it possible to recount a column's value from itself?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example, I have a column as below in my table:

| town | village |

where town = string, village = string

Well, I want to make the village = SUBSTRING(village, 1, (LEN(village)-2))

```
| town | village      |
| Yang | ChenzhuangAA |
| Ling | XianyangAA   |
```

So, I want to remove the last two characters of each row's village. I'd like the table as follows:

```
| town | village      |
| Yang | Chenzhuang   |
| Ling | Xianyang     |
```

May I know how the syntax goes in one GO?

Please guide me. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: well that would be the syntax, in an update statement... e.g. `update mytable set village = SUBSTRING(village, 1, (LEN(village)-2))`

Comment: Yeah, it does work as you said. But I tried the following code before and it threw an exception ... e.g.  update mytable m set village = SUBSTRING(m.village, 1, (LEN(m.village)-2));  When remove the 'm' as you wrote, it worked. Could you tell me why?

Comment: I just knew the reason as Squirrel told me. Thanks again.

Comment: Hopefully, your "village" column is consistent with those extra 2 characters, or else you will find your self removing part of a name!!

Answer (score 3):

simply use LEFT() and length of the string minus 2

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET    village = LEFT(village, LEN(village) - 2)
```

Comment: Thank you, It does work! But I tried the following SQL before and it threw an exception, Could you tell me why?                                                   UPDATE  yourtable w
SET    w.village = LEFT(w.village, LEN(w.village) - 2)

Comment: the text might be less than 2. add a where condition `WHERE LEN(village) > 2`

Comment: @Huang `UPDATE yourtable w` is just incorrect syntax... You'd want to do something like `UPDATE w SET .... FROM mytable w`

Comment: Oh, I got you. Thank you  :)

Answer (score 0):

other way if everything comes as 'AA' then it works and AA comes between string it can handle those type of Data also

```
declare @Table1 TABLE 
    (town varchar(4), village varchar(15))
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (town, village)
VALUES
    ('Yang', 'ChenzhuaangAA'),
    ('Yang', 'ChenzhungAA'),
    ('Ling', 'XianyangAA')
;
```

Script :

```
   update @Table1 
set village = REPLACE(RTRIM(REPLACE(village,'AA',' ')),' ','aa')  
  select * from @Table1
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. I'll try this.